# Android: Display special characters in ListView

Tags: java, android, html, listview

At this moment I am creating a small Android app, as a hobby.
It is not something serious: it makes a query from an sqlite database, and displays the results in a listview element. If you click on an item in the list, it makes another query with the content of the element, and displays the new results. (e.g. You tap on a city, it displays the restaurants in the city. If you tap on the city, it displays the foods available)

Now my problem is that most of these texts contain some special characters (like Ľ - u013D) that are not displayed correctly. And since they are not displayed correctly, I am unable to make further queries with them also.
I have tried many ways, mainly what I saw on this forum, however I am too noob for that unfortunately. This is what I have:

```
//DataBaseHandler is just a custom class creating and executing SQL queries, nothing special. It extends to SQLiteOpenHelper
DataBaseHandler db=new DataBaseHandler(this);

//getStations returns a List<String> object with the required items, contains raw strings        
ArrayList<String> StationList=(ArrayList<String>) db.getStations(i.getStringExtra("jaratszam"));

db.close();

lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listStation);

ArrayAdapter<String> aa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.tv, StationList);          

lv.setAdapter(aa);
```

I have tried to modify the strings I got back with Html.fromHtml, also CharSequence[], but none helped (I guess i did not use them correctly). I have modified my database also, I have changed the special characters to html codes, like

```
&#00E1;
```

Could you please enlighten me what should I do exactly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to user the correct character set for your String, although UTF-8 (which is the default) should support most foreign and special characters. Here's how you create a new String with a custom charset from an old String:

```
String newString = new String(oldString.getBytes(), Charset.YOUR_CHARSET_HERE);
```

Comment: I believe I got the problem finally.
First I tried your solution. It worked perfectly with vowels, but not with consonants.
And then it strucked me: the original encoding! I have generated a script for sqlite that i have saved with with windows' notepad. I was trying to solve this for about 5 hours. Notepad used ANSI encoding by default that i did not notice that screwed up everything. Once I changed it to UTF-8, it worked like a charm! The funny thing is that i had a similar problem about 2 years ago, and it took hours back then also. Well, I hope that I will learn it one day :)

Answer (score 1):

> Now my problem is that most of these texts contain some special
>   characters (like Ľ - u013D) that are not displayed correctly.

Try Encoding your string before putting it in database and decode it before using it in your application.